# JavaScript Class/Constructor vs Definition as Function

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Struggling to find documentation on this.  I previously designed a class in JavaScript something like this:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  area = function() { 
    return this.height * this.width; 
  }
}
```

It didn't work on JSFiddle and I had someone tell me I need to do it this way:

```
var Polygon = function(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
  this.area =  function() { return this.height * this.width; }
}
```

I've seen there's more than one way to do it, I was wondering if this was similar to C++ where you can do like... Polygon *myPoly = new Polygon(3, 4); to make a pointer, as opposed to Polygon myPoly(3, 4);  or if it's just stylistic, and if so any insight as to why one of them doesn't work on JSFiddle and the other does.

Comment: Your pointer question doesn't really apply to JavaScript.  All in memory objects are passed by reference, and functions can natively be passed as Paramus like pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example isn't valid syntax. The correct way to write it would be:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

This should work in JSFiddle if you are using a browser that supports classes, but there are some browsers out there that still do not (more on that below).

Regarding the difference between the two ways to write it, there are two things going on.

First, JavaScript is a very flexible language and there are usually dozens of ways to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Second, the `class` syntax is a fairly new JavaScript feature that is not fully supported across all browsers that are widely in use (particularly, all versions of Internet Explorer). Under the surface, a `class` is really just "syntactic  sugar" for creating constructable objects the way that is shown in your second example, so the end result of those two code examples will be more or less the same.

So to respond to your C++ analogy, no, the two C++ code examples you provided do very different things while these two examples produce almost the same result. To get a result that is almost exactly the same, you could either change the first example to this:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.area = function () { return this.height * this.width; };
  }
}
```

or instead change the second example to this:

```
var Polygon = function(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
};

Polygon.prototype.area = function() { return this.height * this.width; };
```

Comment: OHhhhhhh!  OK, so that's the key, I was running JSFiddle in IE and the local copy in Chrome.  Confirmed this is not a JSFiddle issue, also thanks for the syntax correction.  Follow up though, the second example works for me, any reason to favor doing the prototype modification method?

Comment: @JosephSchmidt The main benefit of using a prototype is that it saves memory. You only have to have one copy of the function in memory, whereas assigning it in the constructor means that each object has its own copy of the function. That really only matters if you will have a large number of those objects. The main point that I wanted to point out is that if you create a `class` and define the `area` method like I did in my first example, what's actually happening behind the scenes is that it is added to a prototype, so the equivalent non-class code would be to use prototype methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code from var area = ... to

```
get area() { return this.height * this.width; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

https://jsfiddle.net/dwahlin/o93Lm0rc/

Comment: It seems the OP wants a method, not a getter.

Comment: @Bergi Yup seems that way, just though of method due to naming convention.

Comment: I haven't come across "get" yet, although I suppose it's basically a getter.  Would you recommend making it a getter instead?

Comment: well it depends the way you want to use. It makes sense to have getter property  with name "area" or method with name "getArea".